# Call a Function inside a innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, function, call, innerhtml

```
.then(function renderTree (data){
  Object.entries(data).map((item, index) => {

    let container = document.querySelector(".container")
    let li = document.createElement("li")
    li.id = `${item[1].id}`
    container.appendChild(li)

    let span = document.createElement("span")
    span.innerHTML = `${item[1].name}`
    li.appendChild(span)

    let ul = document.createElement("ul")
    ul.innerHTML = renderTree(item[1].children)
    li.appendChild(ul)


    // gerarLi(item[1].id, item[1].name)

  })
})
```

I trying to continue the childs inside a `<ul>`, the continuation is in:

```
ul.innerHTML = renderTree(item[1].children)
```

But this code doesn't work, my index.html return like:

```
<ul>undefined</ul>
```

What can I do for this?

Comment: Have you tried to debug and ensure `item[1]` is not undefined? Remember that enumeration in JS starts from 0 and if you want first element it would be `item[0]`.

Comment: I'm also curious about whether there is a reason to use recursion here.  If the data passed in is a knowable list of items, why not just loop through to make each bullet list item?

Answer (score 1):

I made up my own testing `data` and played around with your code a bit. These were the points I found:

- Your recursive function `renderTree()` always placed elements directly into the `.container` div. This should only happen for the outer call.
- You did not `return` anything from your `renderTree()` function.

I changed the function such that it now returns an HTML-string to be placed inside a `<ul>` structure. This function can now safely be called recursively.

```js
const data={abc:{id:"first",name:"number one"}, def:{id:"second",name:"el segundo"},
            ghi:{id:"third",name:"der dritte",
                 children:{jkl:{id:"fourth",name:"child one"},mno:{id:"fifth",name:"child two"}}}};
            
function renderTree(data){ // returns an HTML string for a <UL> DOM element
  return Object.values(data).map(({id,name,children}) => {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.id = id;

    let span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = name;
    li.appendChild(span);

    let ul = document.createElement("ul");
    if (children){
      ul.innerHTML = renderTree(children);
      li.appendChild(ul);
    }
    return li.outerHTML;
  }).join("\n");
}

document.querySelector(".container").innerHTML=renderTree(data);
```

```css
span {color:blue}
```

```html
<ul class="container"></ul>
```

I also changed the `Object.entries()` to `Object.values()` since you never use the keys of the processed objects.